# How to draw Custom Table like below in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody suggest me how to design table like below?[image]

**EDIT**

I have code like below.How can i use `colspan` here for second row.?
and what is the difference between my code and code that is suggested below in answer.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="Server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="1"
                BorderColor="Black" GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="100%">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow
                    runat="server"
                    ForeColor="Black"
                    BackColor="#DCDCDC"
                    Font-Bold="false"
                    align="center"
                    BorderColor="Black">
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableCell20" runat="Server" align="center">Serial No</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableCell21" runat="Server" align="center">Fee Details</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableCell22" runat="Server" align="center">Amount</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow7"
                    runat="Server"
                    BackColor="White"
                    Font-Bold="false"
                    Font-Size="Small">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell13" runat="Server" align="center">
                      1
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell14" runat="Server" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="TypeText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell16" runat="Server" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="FeeText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow6"
                    runat="Server"
                    BackColor="White"
                    Font-Bold="false"
                    Font-Size="Small">


                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell12" runat="Server" align="center">
                       Total Amount
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell15" runat="Server" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="TotalAmountText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                </asp:TableRow>
```

Comment: Use the `column-span` attribute.

Comment: I am unaware of column-span.Can u answer code snippet or suggest some example?

Comment: Why the asp.net tag? Do you need colspan in a GridView?

Answer (score 0):

The table you are requesting can be achieved like so:

```css
.bordered-table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 78px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.bordered-table tr td {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="bordered-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        text
      </td>
      <td>
        text
      </td>
      <td>
        text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
        text
      </td>
      <td>
        text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        text
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
        text
      </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) that can detail the `td colspan` attribute for you.